# NotificationCenter -> extra argument

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notificationcenter

In my app I have complicated architecture, so a little bit of theory at start. When I receive remote notification I call

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification.Name("myName"), 
                                object: nil,
                                userInfo: userInfo)
```

in `AppDelegate`.

In another file I made an `UIViewController` extension with selector function like:

```
func myFunction(_ notification: Notification) { }
```

Now what I do in one of my view controllers (let's call him MyVC) I call

```
override viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector:#selector(myFunction),
                                           name: Notification.Name("myName"),
                                           object: nil)
}
```

`MyVC` contains array with objects. When application receives a push notification I need to process this array inside `myFunction` but in fact I don't know how to pass it.

What I tried was adding extra argument into selector function but unsuccessfully. Can I achieve it somehow?

**Edit:** And what about passing my array into the `object` parameter inside `.addObserver` function? Will I be able to get it in `myFunction` by calling `notification.object`?

Comment: give it a try, and let us know!

Comment: what do you want? do you want to pass data using notifications?

Comment: Pass data from MyVC to myFunction as written in question

Comment: You have to pass data in userInfo dictionary , you cannot pass data with selector

Comment: Know about passing this data through userInfo, but I don't have them while calling `.post` method, only in VC where I have added `.addObserver`.

Comment: you have to send userinfo while posting notification not for registration

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the notification to the `myFunction` by using

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myFunction(_:)), name: Notification.Name("myName"), object: nil)
```

And then process your notification in `myFunction` to extract the data from the notification object's userInfo.

Answer (score 0):

**Receiving a Remote Notification (APN) in AppDelegate :**

```
//---------------------------------------------------------
// Notification event received when APN comes in ... pre 10.0+
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
{
    RemoteNotificationProcessor.handleRemoteNotification(userInfo, handler : completionHandler)
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// UNUserNotificationDelegate implementation 10.0+
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    // Received a Local or Remote Notification (ios 10.0+), we can do what we want
    RemoteNotificationProcessor.handleRemoteNotification(notification, handler : completionHandler)
}
```

**Implementation of RemoteNotificationProcessor (passing on the info):**

```
// NON 10.0+ version....
class func handleRemoteNotification(_ notif : [AnyHashable : Any],
                                    handler : @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
{
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("myName"),
                                                              object: nil,
                                                              userInfo: notif)

    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
class func handleRemoteNotification(_ notif : UNNotification,
                                    handler : @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions)->Void)
{
    guard let trigger = notif.request.trigger else {
        print("Don't know origin of notification trigger")
        handler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
        return
    }
    if trigger is UNPushNotificationTrigger {
        if let json = notif.request.content.userInfo as? [String : Any]
        {
           NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("myName"),
                                                              object: nil,
                                                              userInfo: info)
    }
    else {
        print("Notified other than APN")
    }
    handler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

**Handling data in your #selector**

```
@objc
func myFunction(_ notification : Notification)
{
    if let info = (notification as NSNotification).userInfo {

    }
}
```